# Why is this category invalid?

Tags: category-theory

According to [the Haskell wikibook on Category Theory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory), the category below is not a valid category due to the addition of the morphism *h*. The hint says to " think about associativity of the composition operation." But I don't don't see why it fails.

$$
f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h\\
f \circ (\mathit{id}_B) = (\mathit{id}_A) \circ h\\
$$

Does this then reduce to  $f = h$ ?

And is that not true because *f* and *h*, despite both being from B to A, are not equivalent?

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/6/65/Not-a-cat.png))</sub>

Comment: It is implicit in the picture that $f \ne h$.

Comment: I think you're supposed to assume that every morphism in the category is one of the arrows shown in the diagram, so $fg$, $gf$, $gh$, $hg$, are all identity arrows, and arrows with different labels are distinct (as Zhen Lin said)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It not so clear what is they mean, but I guess what they mean is that if you consider the graph above (in which edges with different labels are different) then you cannot put on that graph a structure of a category.

To prove that you have to use reductio ab absurdum:
if there where any category structure on that graph there should be a law of composition such that $g \circ h = \text{id}_B$ and also $f \circ g = \text{id}_A$ (that's follows for what is said in the link you posted above) and so it should also be the case that
$$f = f \circ \text{id_B} = f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h = \text{id}_A \circ h = h \ .$$

This would implies that $f=h$ but by hypothesis $f \ne h$ hence you've arrived to an absurd, so you cannot find any composition law that give to the graph the structure of a category.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

hint: What is $hgf$? Write it in two different ways.

Comment: I honestly like this answer because it invites me to look at the diagram with this hint and solve this exercise with my eyes (aka diagram chase).

Answer (score 1):

From the graph we see that $f$ *and* $h$ are inverse to $g$. Now it is a general fact about categories that inverses of morphisms are unique. The proof is the same as the one for groups.